# why memcpy in debug version is faster than release version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The following code is faster in debug version than release version(vs2010)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int CNT = 5000;
    const int SIZ = 333333;
    char* p = new char[SIZ];
    char* p2 = new char[SIZ];
    char* p3 = new char[SIZ];
    char* p4 = new char[SIZ];

    for(int i=0;i<SIZ;++i) {  //generate some data
        p3[i] = (char)i;
        p4[i] = (char)(i*2);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < CNT; i++) //make sure memory of p,p2 initialized
    {
        memcpy(p, p3, SIZ);
        memcpy(p2, p4, SIZ);
    }
    LARGE_INTEGER t1,t2;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
    for(int i = 0; i < CNT; i++)
    {
        memcpy(p2, p, SIZ);
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

    DWORD t = t2.LowPart - t1.LowPart;
    printf("%u\n", t);
    printf("%f\n", t * 1.0 / CNT);
    delete[] p;
    delete[] p2;
    int aaa;
    cin>>aaa;
    return 0;


}
```

Debug version:

```
 average running time  is 59.11
 dependcy walker shows that memcpy is in msvcr100D.dll
```

Release version:

```
 average running time  is 65.96
 dependcy walker shows that memcpy is in msvcr100.dll
```

The question is already asked in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8234af2-d7a8-472d-a2b5-cc38cae9364b/release-runs-slower-than-debug-build), 
it was said that:

> "The execution time is dominated by the library function memcpy ,  so
>   any difference in measured speed is mainly due to measurement
>   inaccuracies  (also due to background processes, interrupts etc.)."
>
> "To really see a difference between debug and release try to replace
>   memcpy with mymemcpy:..."

What confuse me is that why memcpy in msvcr100D.dll is faster than the one msvcr100.dll?

I found another link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057825/why-the-release-version-memset-is-slower-than-debug-version-in-visual-studio-201), but it seems that it is not the same case

Comment: When using the non-debug library you're likely also measuring the time to create virtual-to-physical memory mappings. The memory returned by `new` in the debug library is likely to be set to some value, causing actual physical pages to be mapped.  Memory returned from `new` by the non-debug library likely isn't set to any value and therefore isn't mapped to actual physical RAM until you call `memset()`

Comment: did u do what was suggested - replace memcpy by your own implementation

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I only count the time of memcpy " memcpy(p2, p, SIZ);"

Comment: @pm100 Yes, If I change to my own mymemcpy, release version will be faster than debug. But I am wondering why system memcpy give different result

Comment: you actually tried it? Your comment suggests that you think it will be different - not that you tried it

Comment: @pm100, I tried it. After changing memcpy to mymemcpy, the release version is faster than debug version, which is expected.

Comment: Debug and release `memcpy` are identical. The differences are caused by something else. Probably some tiny difference affects the contents of the processor cache in a trivial way, that e.g. happens to keep some data in cache in the debug version which was flushed in the release version. Such things are a) very tricky and b) often not worth chasing down unless they make a big difference. Here they make a tiny difference and are not worth chasing down.

Comment: 10% slower is 10% slower - a compiler optimizer would definitely go after a 10% improvement

Comment: Not sure Andrew's answer covers this case since you had initialized your memory, but I had a similar little benchmark where I was not initializing, and this made a big difference between the numbers I saw in debug and release. So googling and reading Andrew's comment was quite helpful.